Playback failed: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user de
So when a user answer with the correct answer, I want to play the sound. In the contrary, I do not ant the song. This is my code:
`private async Task Notify((string message, bool success) data)
{
    if (data.success)
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("playCorrectAnswerSound");

    Message = data.message;
    Success = data.success;
}`

`function playCorrectAnswerSound() {
    var audio = new Audio('../sounds/CorrectAnswer.mp3');
    audio.play();
}`

This is working on Windows but when I use my Iphone there is no sound and I got the error (Playback failed: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.).
What can I do to get the sound even on IOS?
Have the sound on IOS
